# Resources for finding a word in natural context

Tags: resource-request

Are there any resources for finding examples of texts which use a particular word, in any language?

One would think that Google would be fit for this purpose, however with Google I cannot find a single page which uses the word [vaginate](https://www.google.co.il/#q=vaginate+-define+-dictionary+-pronounce+-translate&start=100) in natural context. All results returned are general reference (dictionaries, pronunciation guides, etc). Though an English word is given for example, this question addresses resources available in any language.

Comment: You're unlikely to find "vaginated" in natural text, because it's not a natural word in English. :)  But good question nonetheless.

Comment: This question appears to refer to [corpus linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corpus_linguistics). As far as I know, corpora are language specific. Linguistics SE has a [tag for questions related to corpore](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/corpora).

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe: Thank you, I'm actually on Linguistics.SE. However I figured that this is a better place to ask as I'm looking for a reference tool.

Comment: I typed in 'vaginates' in Google and on the first page I found the following sentence: "The plasma membrane vaginates the molecules and forms a coated vessel." This is not exactly about flowers, but still a good example sentence for "forming or enclosed in a sheath". On the next page I found: "...much greater than in Amaryllis, of which Blanda vaginates above six inches; but the consequence of this vagination in Haemanthus is a different form of bulb..." Anyway, the majority of words you can find easily on Google, but you picked a very rare one - in what context were you going to use it? Hmm.

Comment: @J.Past: Thank you, upon further digging I did find [that link](http://www.mjguide.com/tutorials/GrowthCont/1718.htm) on page 3 of my search results. Therefore Google _is_ a good resource for finding such data, even if it is buried in the clickbait. You can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it with a note about having to dig deep.

Comment: I agree with Flimzy that it is a good question - as far as the "Resources for finding a word in natural context" part is concerned. But since you used the word 'vaginate' as an example it technically should have the title: "Resources for finding *any* word in natural context - even the *rarest*" And I don't really think anyone has an answer to that... (especially if we consider the criterion "in any language")

Comment: If we remove those criteria of 'all words/rare words' and 'all languages' then you might even find some pages which specialize in **example sentences**. Here is a link to an [English site](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/), here a link to a [German-English site](http://www.vokaboly.de/bs/) (choose 'English' or 'Deutsch'), and here to a [English/Spanish/German/Italian/Portuguese/French site](https://www.foboko.com/dizionario-frase/) (pick a flag). And if you do need to know how to properly use 'vaginate', I guess you will have to ask a Botanist.

Comment: Out of curiosity I've checked various **English corpus** links for your word, but I didn't really get any results - maybe I'm doing something wrong though. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=vaginate&title=Special:Search&go=Go&searchToken=6y449h7rjqd2whvrk75s4wj71) and Google Books still seem to be the easiest. Maybe this is just as effective for other words and other languages as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The type of resource you need appears to be a [text corpus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_corpus). Some corpora are freely available (they can be searched through a web interface or downloaded). Below are a few examples:

- [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) (downloadable);
- [The Collins Corpus](http://www.collins.co.uk/page/The+Collins+Corpus): used for the Collins COBUILD dictionaries; not open;
- [American National Corpus (ANC)](http://www.anc.org/);
- [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/);
- [German Reference Corpus / Deutsches Referenzkorpus (DeReKo)](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/korpora.html);
- [Europarl Parallel Corpus](http://www.statmt.org/europarl/);
- [Russian National Corpus / Национальный корпус русского языка](http://ruscorpora.ru/);
- [National Corpus of Polish / Narodowy Korpus Języka Polskiego NKJP](http://nkjp.pl/index.php?page=0&lang=1);
- [Slovenian National Corpus / Korpus FidaPLUS](http://www.fidaplus.net/Index_eng.htm);
- [Croatian National Corpus / Hrvatski nacionalni korpus, HNK](http://hnk.ffzg.hr/);
- [Corpora built at bmanuel.org](http://www.bmanuel.org/projects/index.html);
- [CORPORA / corpus.byu.edu](http://corpus.byu.edu/): links to other corpora;
- [Tatoeba](http://tatoeba.org/eng/) is a different kind of "corpus" because it is created collaboratively by volunteers who translate sentences for each other.

Answer (score 11):

You can try Linguee.

And this is a dictionary first, but it also provides some real-world-examples:
https://glosbe.com/

You can also try this:  http://corp.hum.sdu.dk/

They all cover only a selection of languages each, though.

Answer (score 9):

For better results than using Google directly, try a "corpus search". Ask Google for "name of language + corpus" and you will find what you need.

For example "Esperanto corpus" gives you these:

http://tekstaro.com/

http://corp.hum.sdu.dk/cqp.eo.html

Answer (score 3):

Just to add another great resource: http://www.dwds.de/
Corpora like this one shows you texts in which the words appear, synonyms and the etymology. 
It's as easy as a Google search.